# Is it possible to run a mySQL query after a set time period?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cron

Bit of an open question as I'm not really sure where to start with this problem, so any suggestions are welcome.

I have a WordPress plugin for listing jobs, with the option to set them as 'featured' - via a checkbox - in the Dashboard.

What I'd like to do is automatically uncheck this option after 72 hours of being posted.

There doesn't seem to be anything in the plugin to handle this.

There is an entry in wp_postmeta which links to the wp_posts table by post_id (the jobs are custom post types). This table has a meta_key named _featured which is Boolean and set to 1 if the 'featured' checkbox is ticked in the dashboard.

There is also a post_date in the wp_posts table.

With all of this information would it be possible to do the following, or am I trying to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut?

GET post_date if post_type is 'job'

CHECK if 72 hours has passed

IF yes SET meta_key _featured to 0

If that logic looks sound how would I then go about implementing it - a mySQL query as a cron job perhaps?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: WordPress has "scheduled events": https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron (and then there's cron itself...)

Comment: Thanks @SergiuParaschiv It seems like wp_schedule_event should be able to query the DB every hour and make the necessary conditional changes